# Finiteness and Countability of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ussing the definitions given by Rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Thrid Edition, p.25):

1. $A$ is *at most countable* if it is *finite* or *countable*

Consider $J = \left\{1,2,\dots \right\}$ and $J_n = \left\{1,2,\dots, n \right\}$. The definitions of a countable set and a finite set are:

2. $A$ is **countable** if $A$ maps **onto** $J$
3. $A$ is **finite** if $A$ maps **onto** $J_n$, for some $n$.

That being defined, consider all possible scenarios for $A$ so that it can be *at most countable* (1)

I would say that:

- If $A$ is finite, it can be related to $J_n$, such that $A$ maps **onto** $J_n$, for some $n$. Since $J_n$ is countable, $A$ must be countable too.
- If $A$ is countable, then.... $A$ it is countable...
- If $A$ is finite and countable..., again, $A$ is countable by definition.

There is no way I can use  *at most countable*, because to my point of view, all of the posibilities given in (1) are being analyzed resulting in countable sets, in other words, to me, there is no need of using *at most...*. I've been thinking for hours to find an answer... any hint is well appreciated before the answer :)

Comment: Why did you delete and repost the same question?  I was typing an answer as you deleted it.

Comment: Please check the definition.  I am used to onto just meaning the map is surjective, that every element in the range is the image of at least one element of the domain.  In that case every nonempty set maps onto $J_1$.  You seem to be using onto as a bijection.  Maybe that is part of mapping for Rudin.

Comment: @RossMillikan Because I didn't check if it was a repeated question... I didn't find it tho... My bad. I am really sorry.

Rudin uses "onto" as follows: If $A$ and $B$ are two sets, and $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, then $f(A) = B$ can be read as $f$ maps $A$ onto $B$. Also, you can write it as $A \sim B$... I think this is the same as surjection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined here, "countable" is the same as "countably infinite" and a finite set is not countable.  Your first bullet is incorrect.  In that case $A$ is not countable.  If $A$ is finite, it cannot map onto $J$.

Other authors include finite sets as countable.  You need to check the definition in use.

Comment: I am mapping $A$ onto $J_n$, for some $n$. Both of them being finite.

Comment: None of the $J_n$ are countable by Rudin's definition because a set has to be infinite to be countable.

Comment: Ok, so that's why Rudin uses "at most countable" for finite sets, and just "countable" for the infinite sets.

Comment: Exactly.  As I said, the definition of countable sometimes includes finite sets.  You need to check what each author uses.  I don't know which is the majority approach.